# ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() error when finding layout by ID

Tags: java, android-layout, filenotfoundexception

I'm a rookie. This is my onCreate method from MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(this);  
    np.setId(10);
    np.setMaxValue(6);
    np.setMinValue(2);
    np.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout.addView(np);
}
```

When this code is executed, none of the View elements is shown on the Android screen and the 'zygoteInit error' pops out in Eclipse. How should I change the findViewById command in the line before the last to be able to add a View (NumberPicker) to the LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById(R.layout.activity_main)`

Wrong! `R.layout` identifies the entire layout, not any view within that layout. When you call `findViewById` you must pass `R.id.<something>`.